# Is there a term for minor "additional" lyrics in songs?

Tags: single-word-requests, lyrics

Many songs have "minor" phrases added in - either officially or in common practice - at the ends of lines, which comment on the lyrics but can be left out without affecting the lyrics' meaning.

For example, when people sing "Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer", at the end of the line "had a very shiny nose" they often add "(like a light bulb!)".

These seem especially common in rap songs, where they are usually very short and written in parentheses in the written lyrics. For example, in 50 Cent's "In Da Club", at the end of the line "Been hit with a few shells, but I don't walk with a limp" he adds a quick "(I'm aight)".

Is there a term for these minor/optional and short "additional, background" lyrics?

Comment: Have you considered asking this on [music.se]? We are not domain experts in all possible things.

Comment: I'd call improvised lyrics *improv*.

Comment: They could be called glosses.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I don't think that these phrases are usually improvised, though.

Comment: @Xanne I've never heard of the word "gloss" being used in that way - do you have a citation?

Comment: Then maybe you see such as an aside, a side comment. Like when Ross adds the parenthetical dismay in "You Keep Me A Hangin’ On”: "Set me free ... When seeing you only breaks my heart again? **(And there ain't nothing I can do about it).**"

Comment: @tchrist Another desirable set CV comment (with a slot for the dedicated site).

Comment: Sometimes called **patter**?

Comment: @WeatherVane Ooh, patter, a very apt label.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I would have posted that as answer but can't find a good supporting  reference.

Comment: Round here, these would be *parentheticals* or *parenthetical lyrics* or maybe *interjections*.

Comment: If sung by the lead singer, I'd run with *embellishments* until someone over at music produces a term that's comprehensible in English, and they probably will.

Comment: Can we restrict the question to things like Rudolph where people shout a response to certain lyrics? The other thing is separate, where a rapper or singer offers asides or commentary, often in a lower voice or more conversational tone.

Comment: @StuartF You can do whatever you want! :-)

Comment: See MW’s definitions of gloss as commentary on  or explanation of text.

Answer (score 0):

(Semi-improvisational) phrases in music and other performing arts are shortly referred to in English to '[ad-libs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_libitum)'. But this is short for the latin 'ad libitum' (as you desire); this question is probably more suited for the music stackexchange, as noted by @tchrist.

Comment: I don’t think that these kind of phrases are usually improvised, though - they seem quite standardized.

Comment: @tparker much 'improvisation' is standardized! hence the popular 'skrt', 'pshh', 'brrr', etc. even producer/rapper tags are used as pseudo-ad-libs in many tracks

Comment: They are not ad-libs, which are improvised. Those in the ancient Gilbert & Sullivan musicals for example are traditional extra lines. More like *de rigueur*.

Comment: They might have been ad libs originally, but they've caught on and have become common. Kind of like "extra" rules in Monopoly such as winning the Free Parking money when you land on Go.

Comment: Sometimes called an [aside](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aside) perhaps, *an actor's speech heard by the audience but supposedly not by other characters*.

Comment: @WeatherVane is 'they' referring to the general class OP is interested in, and the given examples? not sure how 50 Cent would respond to his lyrics being described as _de rigueur_...

Comment: If you mean in an artist's own work, then no. Those are part of the song, and more like an 'aside'. In Rudolf and G&S they might be *de rigueur*.